# Add Bitmap to HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have an ASP.NET web form. This web form has an event handler that generates some HTML. This HTML is based on the time-of-day, that is why it is created in the event handler. Based on the time of day, an image is created programmatically via the following method:

```
private Bitmap GetImageForTime(DateTime time)
{
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();

  // Dynamically build the bitmap...

  return bitmap;
}
```

I want to call this method when the HTML is being generated. However, I do NOT want to write the image on the server. Instead, I would like to figure out a way to write it out along with the HTML. In a sense, I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
protected void myLiteral_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string html = "<table><tr><td>";
  html += GetImageForTime(DateTime.Now);  // This is the problem because it's binary.
  html += "</td><td>";
  html += GetWeatherHtmlText();
  html += "</td></tr></table>";
  myLiteral.Text = html;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another aspx page called `TimeImage.aspx` then in the Page_Load of the code-behind for the page put this code:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    string mime = "image/jpeg";
    Response.ContentType = mime;

    Bitmap b = GetImageForTime(DateTime.Now);

    var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Where(i => i.MimeType == mime).SingleOrDefault();

    if(codec != null)
        b.Save(Response.OutputStream, codec, null);
}
```

Then make your html generation look like this:

```
protected void myLiteral_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string html = "<table><tr><td>";
  html += "<img src='TimeImage.aspx'>"
  html += "</td><td>";
  html += GetWeatherHtmlText();
  html += "</td></tr></table>";
  myLiteral.Text = html;
}
```

This will create an img tag that calls the `TimeImage.aspx` page, that page changes the response mime-type to `image/jpeg`, converts your bitmap to a JPG, and then saves it to the response output stream so that the image tag can display it as a JPG.

If you prefer a different format just change the mime type at the top (e.g. "image/gif" for GIF, or "image/png" for PNG).

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest implementing an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) that generates your image and returns it as a byte stream.  Then in the  tag on the page, set the src attribute to the address of the HTTP Handler.

```
<html><body><img src="TimeImageHandler.ashx"/></body></html>
```

Example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/desaijm/httphandlersforimages11152005062705am/httphandlersforimages.aspx

Generic HTTP Handlers are pretty simple to create once you're aware of them:

```
public class TimeImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = GetImageForTime(DateTime.Now);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        bitmap.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this is to create an image tag in the HTML and point the image source (`<img src="xxx" />`) to a page that dynamically creates the image and returns that (and only that) on the response stream, with the correct mime type.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially you could use the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in [an `<img>` tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) or [in some CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#CSS) but personally, I wouldn't.

[Some more explanation.](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/07/howto-include-binary-image-data-in-cascading-style-sheets-css.html)

Comment: I always liked it but unluckly discovered at the time I made my tests, it was not so widely supported (in particular, it was not supported by IE, I don't know anything about current vers anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Images in HTML are displayed as a result of an `<img>` element in the HTML. I don't believe there is any other way to display an image in an HTML page.

You will need to write a handler which can be invoked via the URL in the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element. That handler will generate and return the image.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the already given solutions of using the data URI scheme *or sending the image dynamically created (so, without storing it)*, there's another odd solution you can try: a table with each cell 1-pixel tall and wide and proper background per cell, and no borders of course... GIMP e.g. is able to export images this way as html, and if you force the size of cells and table, you can see the image as if it were embedded... of course, it is rather "heavy" if the image is big, but it could work ok for relatively small images.

**EDITED** (italics part added)

Comment: Of course doing the example of GIMP I am not saying you use it to do that... I am just saying it is easy to be done someway, it's like generating a normal table in html, so lots of `html +=` ...